# The [project-management] clean-up project

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Take a look at this SO search query: [`[project-management] closed:no locked:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bproject-management%5D%20closed%3Ano%20locked%3Ano)

The tag says:

> Project management... questions are now off-topic on SO

Some of the questions are mistagged, such as `Python Project Structure` (I assume they typed all the words in the title and picked the first tag). These should be retagged, obviously, and can probably remain open.

Many of the questions under the tag are highly voted, but off-topic now. It's important to deal with this, otherwise, they could show up in audits.

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It describes contents of the question, but it's an ambiguous term.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

No, it's not.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

It does for off-topic questions which should be locked, closed or deleted. For the rest, the tag is misused as described above.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No.

Comment: I swept through a bunch of these a couple of days ago, deleting and closing the blatantly off topic ones I saw. When I did that, I noticed that were a number of decent questions about managing project files within various IDEs (Xcode, etc.). These didn't need to be migrated or closed, and I wasn't even sure about re-tagging them. We certainly don't want to blindly migrate all of these or close all of them. While the tag has been used for a number of off-topic questions, I'm not sure it should be removed entirely from the site.

Comment: @BradLarson I mentioned that there are some relevant questions that  have the tag. They should be retagged, as the [project-management] tag is about *managing people on a project* not managing things on a computer.

Comment: @BradLarson tag is most definitely wrong fit in IDE related questions, just [take a look at its wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/project-management/info): **"Project management is the discipline of planning, organizing, securing, and managing resources to achieve specific goals. Such questions are now off-topic on SO..."**

Comment: @BradLarson Yes, I've seen the questions about managing projects within IDEs. They're on-topic here, but they are also technically misuses of the [project-management] tag. That tag is about the [project-management] discipline (which is now entirely off-topic here), not about how to use IDEs.