# Blacklist [agile], [scrum] and [project-management]

Tags: discussion, tags, blocklist-request

- [agile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile) - 1282 questions
- [scrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrum) - 884 questions
- [project-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-management) - 1796 questions (and that's after a [cleanup effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320633/the-project-management-clean-up-project))
- [agile-processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile-processes) - 64 questions
- [kanban](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kanban) - 142 questions
- [agile-project-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/agile-project-management) - 87 questions

Agile and Scrum are project management methodologies.

We have [Software Engineering](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Project Management](//pm.stackexchange.com/) to discuss all three. There are no on-topic questions for these tags. But, as [Brad Larson noted for [project-management]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320633/the-project-management-clean-up-project#comment331230_320633)

> I noticed that were a number of decent questions about managing project files within various IDEs (Xcode, etc.). These didn't need to be migrated or closed, and I wasn't even sure about re-tagging them. We certainly don't want to blindly migrate all of these or close all of them. While the tag has been used for a number of off-topic questions, I'm not sure it should be removed entirely from the site.

Blacklisting is the best solution here. Prevents future questions and we can leave the good historical questions in place.

Comment: `Please do it `

Comment: Let's also get waterfall while we're at it. Don't even know if that's a tag but I'm all for killing these 'project management workflow' tags... ...and the workflows IRL, too.

Comment: I agree with @TylerH - these tags are worthless and mostly off-topic. There are qute a few of them, such as [kanban], that should all just be closed.

Comment: Please add `extreme-programming` to this list.  Another methodology _du jour_ that IMO has no place here.

Comment: `pair-programming` is another candidate for removal.

Comment: Burndown [agile], [scrum], and [project-management]

Comment: [Related.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289953/how-to-proceed-with-the-agile-tag?rq=1) [Related.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues?rq=1)

Comment: I think the title should be "*something something* and friend", otherwise it will always be inaccurate.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with this. We should burninate the tags while they're at it (or at least initiate a large-scale cleanup effort).

These tags are classic candidates for burnination because, while they're *technically* unambiguous, they're unambiguously describing something that's not even on topic here. The vast majority of these questions should either be closed and deleted outright or migrated to other sites (Software Engineering SE or Project Management SE).

For those who'd like to get started on cleaning this up, there are currently numerous off-topic questions in the close vote queues if you'd like to filter on these tags. For those that don't have close vote rights yet, it's still *tremendously* helpful to go through the questions and flag low-quality and off-topic questions so that people can filter on them.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356963/tag-removals-must-be-discussed-and-documented-on-meta => https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071 (Remember that you must follow the process.)

Comment: @CodyGray You mean with a separate post for the burnination?

Comment: No, I mean with not encouraging vigilante retagging and cleanup efforts. On that note, I've been planning to feature one of these burninate requests, but the team keeps featuring announcements. There's been a *lot* of Meta activity lately. Even more posts incoming in the next few days.

Comment: @CodyGray I wasn't encouraging vigilante retagging/cleanup, merely making the argument that there should be an "official" cleanup effort. I can post that as a separate request if necessary, I was just concerned that if I did it would be dupe-hammered.

Comment: We have plenty of requests, @EJoshuaS.

Comment: @CodyGray Yes, I am aware that burnination requests are quite backlogged right now, so maybe the "official" request should wait.

Comment: @CodyGray Upon further reflection, it seems like general cleanup and blacklisting may be adequate. At a minimum, there are enough high-scored questions that are too old to migrate that it seems like a very difficult/risky burnination that could result in lost content. Do you know what happens to "straight" blacklist requests? Do they have to be featured for a few days like burnination requests to give people a chance to object, or can you just flag for moderator intervention or otherwise ping a CM once it reaches a certain score?