# We can get rid of this tag with [teamwork]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [teamwork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teamwork) tag currently contains <s>69</s> 8 (thanks to [Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356197/we-can-get-rid-of-this-tag-with-teamwork?noredirect=1#comment511576_356197) and others) *closed* questions, and no open ones. Its excerpt is

> Groups of people working cooperatively to complete a task.

which is very general. Whilst I can imagine questions which might be on-topic on Stack Overflow, such as those about github usage with a group of developers, none of the current questions are on-topic, hence every one of those is closed.

Should we take the next step and just burninate it all together?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351809/blacklist-agile-scrum-and-project-management

Comment: How'd they *all* get closed? Was that just an amazing coincidence? Or was there some kind of prior clean-up of this tag?

Comment: @CodyGray I can only speak for the last 5 question to be closed, they were mentioned in the SOCVR, as all being POB or Too broad, so we voted accordingly. The other 64 posts were closed prior to that.

Comment: @CodyGray There was clean-up by me previously. I've cleaned and retagged bunch of questions. Also I've asked SOCVR several times to help me close open off-topic questions, and here are the results.

Comment: I'd recommend deleting the questions while they're all conveniently grouped, rather than just removing the tag from each one.

Comment: I deleted all the questions with this tag that had no redeeming value. The rest of them have answers that *look* like they might contain some useful information. I'm guessing the community will probably want to delete them all anyway, but I'm not going to...

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks! Could you please clarify what will be the next step?

Comment: A lot of these questions would seem to have useful lasting values, and so we should make an effort to retain them somehow. One option would be to repost them as community wiki answers in the relevant  SE forums (if relevant dupes do not already exist) and then just delete these.

Comment: Title suggestion: Can we get rid of [teamwork] on stackoverflow

Comment: @Ferrybig nope.

Comment: All of these questions are closed now - what to do with them?

Comment: @EJoshuaS that's indeed the question here, since this has been the state of the tag (and indeed this question) for the past three weeks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All questions were deleted, tag is gone now. I am posting this as answer just for making this accepted by OP.