# I use the [project-management] tag for most of my poll questions, what do you use?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, burninate-request

Related: [Blacklist [agile], [scrum] and [project-management]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351809/blacklist-agile-scrum-and-project-management)

Also related: [Do we really need these Software Engineering related tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355013/do-we-really-need-these-software-engineering-related-tags)

While the [project-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-management) tag isn't a Meta tag and unambiguously identifies a topic, it unambiguously identifies something that's very clearly off-topic.

We now have Software Engineering and Project Management SE for these questions.

While a few of the questions are on, for example, how to manage Visual Studio projects, the questions that are legitimately on-topic here are the exception rather than the norm; in fact, they're not even correct uses of the tag. The tag is about Project Management as a discipline, not about how to properly use IDEs. The programming concept of projects like you find in Visual Studio and IDEs is an entirely unrelated concept. These questions should be re-tagged.

The [project-management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-management) tag currently has 837 open questions and 801 closed questions (which is at least partially due to concerted efforts to clean up the tag). Most of the remaining questions are off-topic and/or primarily opinion-based; in particular, it attracts a very large number of poll questions (["I use ____ for ____, what do you use?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)).

Incidentally, there are questions from this tag in the close vote queue if anyone has spare votes and would like to filter on it.

Comment: You still have to deal with [what Brad Larson noted here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320633/the-project-management-clean-up-project#comment331230_320633). I'm not sure burnination is the right thing in light of that

Comment: @Machavity I disagree with him about the IDE questions - those questions are a misuse of the tag and ought to be re-tagged. All correct uses of the tag are off-topic here.

Comment: @Machavity At a minimum, the tags should be cleaned up. After that, we should blacklist them like you suggested in the linked post to prevent people from further abusing them.

Comment: @Clive How's the new title?

Comment: That thing's still around? I [thought we had discussed this a while back](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues)...